# Expand Behavior's Grouped pages in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, pages

Google Analytics groups multiple pages together under the Behavior section making it difficult to trace a user's flow from page to page.  For instance, at the bottom of Behavior Flow, there's usually a group named (X more pages), but not a direct way to link the pages in this grouped box to the next page a user followed.

See image:
[image]

You can use the +/- arrows next to the little house icon in the upper left corner to increase the size of the boxes, but it doesn't expand the names.  You can also click on a group and show details, but it won't show you how contained pages link to the next page.

Is there a way to show the page name in one of these grouped containers and how it links to the next page?